# Rails generate model refrences but not belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have a Ruby-on-Rails application that should have the following models: `Order`, `OrderItem`, and `Product`

I wanted to generate the `OrderItem` model, for this I used:

```
rails g model OrderItem order:references product:references quantity:integer selling_price:decimal
```

The result model is:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Technically, the `OrderItem` correctly belongs_to `Order` this is correct. Technically however it does not "belong to" but at most `has_one :product`. Changing this by correcting the generated model is of course easy. Been wondering if there's a correct Ruby way for generating a has_one relation though. Was using references in this case wrong, and there's a correct way to do this?

Comment: The generated code is correct. The `belongs_to :product` will look for the foreign key `product_id` under `order_items`, the `has_one :product` will look for the `order_item_id` under `products`. [More info here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

Comment: Semantically this is very weird though. Can't quite accept that order_item "belongs to" product. It "has one" product to me makes much more sense. Can I find any explanations on this any where?